# How to perform parallel growth mixture modeling (GMM) using R?

Tags: r, classification, mixture-model, multilevel-analysis

Usually, i'm using "lcmm" package in R - in order to perform growth mixture modeling (GMM).
However, i want to create a classification or groups based on two variables rather than one. I've read that this kind of modeling called "parallel growth mixture modeling". Is anyone knows how to perform such an analysis using R script?